# calling django url through javascript with parameters

Tags: javascript, django

This is my javascript function where I pass parameters, using alert I checked that function is getting the parameters I want but I am unable to pass them in django url other wise giving a string the url works but not with parameters.

```
      function myFunction(a) {
      var v = a.value;
      alert(v);
      location.href="{% url 'new_event' v %}"; //does not works
      location.href="{% url 'new_event' 'string' %}"; //works
      }
```

I have checked the value getting is string the way I want but how to pass it?

Comment: This is likely *not* due to the parameter in the URL, but because the URL contains escaped characters, or quotes, etc.

Comment: I am actually passing date and time in url for the sake of simplicity only used string in this post,  the actual url is {% url 'new_event' '08:30:00' '2018-10-08' %}

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
location.href = "/" + v
```

where v is your id or slug

Answer (score 0):

kindly try this:

```
    function myFunction(a) {
        var v = a.value;
        alert(v);
        location.href="{% url 'new_event' v %}"; // this will not work because your django **url** filter is pre-processed on your server while your javascript variable is processed on **client**
        // if you want your variable v to be dynamic, you need to include it in your django's view **context**
        location.href="{% url 'new_event' 'string' %}"; //works
    }

    // include in your views.py
    context['v'] = 'some-string'

    // template.html
    <script>
        function myFunction(a) {
            var v = '{{ v }}'; // javascript variable v
            alert(v);
            location.href="{% url 'new_event' v %}"; // django context variable v
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Reverse for 'new_event' with no arguments not found